# How html2pdf generate pdf without media query css?

Tags: css, html2pdf

I'm making a RWD table, and using html2pdf to generate pdf file.
And I using media query to change small screen style like:

`@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { /*small screen style*/ }`

Is there a way can I genetate pdf by small screen, but without media query css?
Please tell me if you have better solution. Thanks!

Comment: since the output of that page will be expected to be rendered on an A4 page (or any target you know upfront) just take the css rules embedded in any of the media query you think that best applies to that target and put them outside the media query. Then just delete all the other ones.

Comment: Make your media queries dependent on a common parent of it all (such as the html element) having a specific class - and then just remove that class, before you trigger the PDF generation ...?

Answer (score 0):

I thinl i figure it out.
use a specific class for media query than remove it!
https://codepen.io/junjunfan/pen/LYBobgd

```js
function generatePDF() {
  const rootNode = document.querySelector("#print_content")
  const opt = {
    // margin: 10,
    filename: 'mypdf.pdf',
    jsPDF: { format: 'b4', orientation: 'portrait' },
    html2canvas:  { 
      scale: 4,
      useCORS: true,
      height: 1200,
    }
  }
  $(".container").removeClass("mqcss");
   

  const element = rootNode;

  html2pdf()
    .set(opt)
    .from(element)
    .save();
}

document.getElementById('exportPDF').addEventListener('click', generatePDF);
 $(".container").addClass("mqcss");
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  background-color: #eee;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container p {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .mqcss {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .mqcss p {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.9.2/html2pdf.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="print_content">

  <div class="container mqcss">
    <p>RWD Content</p>
  </div>

</div>
<button id="exportPDF">generate PDF</button>
```